# Whay can't I convert this name into an email link with the first name abbreviated?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
$name = 'billy, jole';
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z,]+ ([a-zA-Z]+)/',$name ,$yes)){
          print preg_replace('/(^[a-zA-Z,]+), ([a-zA-Z])+/','<a href="mailto:$1@ccsf.edu"></a>', $name);
}
```

The output is:

```
<a href="mailto:billy@ccsf.edu"></a>
```

But I need the first name abbreviated to jbilly so the output looks like this:

```
<a href="mailto:jbilly@ccsf.edu"></a>
```

Can someone please help me? I am new to regular expressions?

Comment: will fail on more than half of the worlds names

Comment: The code provided doesn't do anything.

Comment: Not sure how. I must have edit my code by mistake. The code is working now. Just not giving the desired output.

Comment: where do you do the abbreviation? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: Instead of billy I want the first initial next to the last name like jbilly.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the first letter separately.  And watch where you put your parentheses; it looks like you threw them around a bit haphazardly.

```
$name = 'billy, jole';
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+, [a-z]+/i', $name, $yes)) {
    print preg_replace('/^([a-z]+), ([a-z])[a-z]*/i', '<a href="mailto:$2$1@ccsf.edu"></a>', $name);
}
```

Of course, as pointed out, this will fail on a great many names and name formats, and very few organizations actually manage to use first-letter-last-name for very long before they run into collisions or edge cases.

Comment: You're right and thanks for the tips. My assignment has a list of names that are all formatted the same with no unique names.

Answer (score 0):

> I had a problem that I tried to solve with regular expressions. Now I have two problems.

If you're dealing with the format `lastname, firstname` your regular expression is going to break in the case of names like `van O'Toole, Sëamus`. You *could* write a truly horrible regular expression, or you could just split on the comma and trim whitespace.

```
$name = "van O'Toole, Sëamus"

list($lname, $fname) = array_map('trim', explode(',', $name));
```

Then to create the email address:

```
// convert to lowercase, strip special chars.
$fname = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', strtolower($fname));
$fname = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', strtolower($lname));

$email = sprintf("%s%s@domain.com", substr($fname,0,1), $lname);

//result: svanotoole@domain.com
```

Comment: but then would an automated system have called this person `svanotoole` or `sotoole`?  almost like names are hard to slop around programmatically...  :)